# É possivel instanciar um objeto mais de uma vez em uma classe?

Tags: java

estou com um problema. Tenho 3 For's, um dentro do outro,
Dentro do segundo For eu faço a instância do meu objeto e logo após passo os dados de um arquivo xml que eu leio para esse objeto e no final adiciono tudo em uma `List<MeuObjeto>`.
Porém no terceiro FOR eu precisava instanciar novamente meu objeto, pois quando passo o dado para o objeto ele só armazena o primeiro elemento. Aqui está um trecho do código:

```
 for (int y = 0; y < tagdadosGuia.getLength(); y++) {

                NodeList tagBeneficiario0 = ((Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:beneficiario");
                NodeList tagProcedimentos = ((Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:procedimentos");
                NodeList tagProcedimentos1 = ((Element) tagProcedimentos.item(0)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:dadosProcedimento");
                NodeList tagProcedimento = ((Element) tagProcedimentos1.item(0)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:procedimento");

                Element elementoBeneficiariox = (Element) tagBeneficiario0.item(0);
                String name = pegaTag(elementoBeneficiariox, "unimed:nomeBeneficiario");
                String nome = null;

                for (int a = 0; a < tagProcedimentos1.getLength(); a++) {
                    UnimedLote contato = new UnimedLote();

                    contato.setNumLote(lote);
                    nome = name;
                    System.err.println("Nomes: " + nome);
                    contato.setNomeBeneficiario(nome);

                    Element elementoBeneficiario12 = (Element) tagProcedimentos1.item(a);
                    String tot = pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario12, "unimed:valorInformado");
                    if (tot
                            == null) {
                        tot = "0";
                    }
                    BigDecimal vt = new BigDecimal(tot).setScale(2);
                    contato.setValorTotalInformado(vt);

                    /*Beneficiarios*/
                    Element elementoBeneficiario0 = (Element) tagBeneficiario0.item(0);
                    beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario0, "unimed:numeroCarteira"));
                    contato.setCodigo(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario0, "unimed:numeroCarteira"));

                    /*Dados das Guias*/
                    Element elementoBeneficiario1 = (Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y);
                    beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario1, "unimed:numeroGuiaOperadora"));
                    contato.setNumeroDocumento(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario1, "unimed:numeroGuiaOperadora"));

                    Element elementoBeneficiario2 = (Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y);
                    beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario2, "unimed:valorProcessadoGuia"));
                    Element elementoBeneficiario3 = (Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y);
                    beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario3, "unimed:valorLiberadoGuia"));

                    Element elementoBeneficiario03 = (Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y);
                    String valorGlosa = (pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario03, "unimed:valorGlosaGuia"));
                    contato.setTipoGlosa(valorGlosa);

                    /*Dados das Guias*/

                    /*Procedimentos*/
                    Element elementoBeneficiario4 = (Element) tagProcedimentos1.item(a);
                    beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario4, "unimed:valorProcessado"));
                    Element elementoBeneficiario5 = (Element) tagProcedimentos1.item(a);
                    beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario5, "unimed:dataProcedimento"));
                    //contato.setData(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario5, "unimed:dataProcedimento"));

                    String d = pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario5, "unimed:dataProcedimento");
                    //Primeiro converte de String para Date
                    DateFormat formatUS = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
                    Date date = null;
                    try {
                        date = formatUS.parse(d);
                    } catch (ParseException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(LeitorXml1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                    //Depois formata data
                    DateFormat formatBR = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
                    String dateFormated = formatBR.format(date);

                    contato.setData(dateFormated);
                    for (int b = 0; b < tagProcedimento.getLength(); b++) {

                        //Procedimento(tag que fica dentro de procedimentos)!!
                        Element elementoBeneficiario6 = (Element) tagProcedimento.item(0);
                        beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario6, "unimed:codigo"));
                        contato.setProcedimento(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario6, "unimed:codigo"));

                        Element elementoBeneficiario7 = (Element) tagProcedimento.item(0);
                        beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario7, "unimed:descricao"));
                        contato.setDescricaoProced(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario7, "unimed:descricao"));

                        //Procedimento(tag que fica dentro de procedimentos)!!
                    listaLote.add(contato);                       
}
```

---

Atualização:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na Imagem a descrição  que é Seringa... Se repete pelos demais pois é o primeiro dado do arquivo xml, eu só consigo pegar todos os dados quando eu instancio o objeto dentro do FOR

Se quiser conferir o trecho do .xml, está aqui:

```
<unimed:procedimentos>
                    <unimed:dadosProcedimento>
                      <unimed:seqLote>2</unimed:seqLote>
                      <unimed:seqGuia>2</unimed:seqGuia>
                      <unimed:seqProc>1</unimed:seqProc>
                      <unimed:procedimento>
                        <unimed:codigo>22222</unimed:codigo>
                        <unimed:tipoTabela>19</unimed:tipoTabela>
                        <unimed:descricao>SERINGA S/AG.20ML LUER SLIP PLASTIP</unimed:descricao>
                      </unimed:procedimento>
                      <unimed:quantidadeExecutada>3</unimed:quantidadeExecutada>
                      <unimed:valorProcessado>4.53</unimed:valorProcessado>
                      <unimed:valorLiberado>4.53</unimed:valorLiberado>
                      <unimed:dataProcedimento>2015-03-26</unimed:dataProcedimento>
                      <unimed:valorFilme>0</unimed:valorFilme>
                      <unimed:valorServico>4.5300</unimed:valorServico>
                      <unimed:valorHonorario>0</unimed:valorHonorario>
                      <unimed:numAutorizacao>4111421</unimed:numAutorizacao>
                      <unimed:prestadorExecutante>44444</unimed:prestadorExecutante>
                      <unimed:valorInformado>4.5300</unimed:valorInformado>
                    </unimed:dadosProcedimento>
                    <unimed:dadosProcedimento>
                      <unimed:seqLote>2</unimed:seqLote>
                      <unimed:seqGuia>2</unimed:seqGuia>
                      <unimed:seqProc>2</unimed:seqProc>
                      <unimed:procedimento>
                        <unimed:codigo>333333</unimed:codigo>
                        <unimed:tipoTabela>19</unimed:tipoTabela>
                        <unimed:descricao>SCALP NR.27G MEDSCALP EMB.PLAST.</unimed:descricao>
                      </unimed:procedimento>
                      <unimed:quantidadeExecutada>1</unimed:quantidadeExecutada>
                      <unimed:valorProcessado>2.58</unimed:valorProcessado>
                      <unimed:valorLiberado>2.58</unimed:valorLiberado>
                      <unimed:dataProcedimento>2015-03-26</unimed:dataProcedimento>
                      <unimed:valorFilme>0</unimed:valorFilme>
                      <unimed:valorServico>2.5800</unimed:valorServico>
                      <unimed:valorHonorario>0</unimed:valorHonorario>
                      <unimed:numAutorizacao>4444444</unimed:numAutorizacao>
                      <unimed:prestadorExecutante>4444444</unimed:prestadorExecutante>
                      <unimed:valorInformado>2.5800</unimed:valorInformado>
                    </unimed:dadosProcedimento>
                    <unimed:dadosProcedimento>
                      <unimed:seqLote>2</unimed:seqLote>
                      <unimed:seqGuia>2</unimed:seqGuia>
                      <unimed:seqProc>3</unimed:seqProc>
                      <unimed:procedimento>
                        <unimed:codigo>4444444</unimed:codigo>
                        <unimed:tipoTabela>19</unimed:tipoTabela>
                        <unimed:descricao>AGULHA HIPODERMICA 40X12 PRECISIONG</unimed:descricao>
                      </unimed:procedimento>
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, você quer um novo objeto igual ao anterior no inicio do terceiro for e então dentro dele você altera o `procedimento` e a `descricaoProced`?

Comment: Isso, o xml que tenho está mal escrito e essa foi a solução que encontrei para pegar várias tags. Dentro do terceiro for, ele nao está repetindo os dados, ou seja, só pega o ultimo dado. Vou mostrar uma imagem

Comment: O seu `listaLote.add(contato)` está dentro ou fora do último `for`? Basicamente se você colocar dentro vai funcionar, ele vai add 1 objeto para cada tag. Já fora ele só pega a última mesmo, pois a cada iteração do for sobrescreve a anterior, uma alternativa seria criar uma `list` de tags e setar ela no objeto.

Comment: Ele está dentro do ultimo For, tem mais um for que é responsável por Pegar o Node principal

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta

Comment: E eu me equivoquei tambem, nao é o ultimo elemento que está sendo pego e sim o primeiro

Comment: Consegui, coloquei a Lista dentro do ultimo for, coloquei ele lá em cima logo após o segundo e deu certo. Coloca uma resposta para que eu possa marcar como solução

Comment: @DiegoAugusto você mesmo pode publicar a sua reposta e marcar como reposta correta, não há nada de errado nisto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicionei a `listaLote.add(contato)` dentro do ultimo `FOR` e meu problema foi resolvido